# How to say "Because it was predicted that the typhoon would pass over PLACE-X on DATE-Y"?

Tags: sentence-structure

How to say

```
Because it was predicted that the typhoon would pass over PLACE-X on DATE-Y?
```

A probably very problematic translation could be:

```
因為預計DATE-Y颱風來PLACE-X
```

In particular, I would like to ask if the sentence should be re-ordered, as well as what is a more specific word to use in this case, instead of the generic 來. Lastly I am not sure at all whether or not it is OK to use 預計.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because it was predicted that the typhoon would pass over PLACE-X on DATE-Y
>
> 因為預計颱風會在 Y月Y日 吹襲 X市

*Do you really need '因為'(because) in this sentence? If you use 'because' to start a sentence, you have to use '所以' (therefore) to end the sentence*

"因為預計颱風會在 Y月Y日 吹襲 X市" is an incomplete sentence

"預計颱風會在 Y月Y日 吹襲 X市" is a complete sentence

*When describe a 颱風 hitting a place, we use the term '吹襲'*